# RDP to Virtual Machine now asking for user sign in

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, rdp

We have a Windows Server 2012 VM that I installed a product on: Smart Bear TestExecute(v15.43 - latest): https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/other-tools/testexecute.html

I was trialling something and have now removed the software.

I have now noticed that when RDP onto the VM I am now prompted for username/password as a sign on:
[image]

instead of within the Remote Desktop dialog as it was before:

[image]

I suspect the software installation has changed some settings on the VM in order to support the execution of tests running from TestExecute.

Any help would be appreciated. I presume this is a simple enough setting change but I don't have the expertise to know where to look.

Comment: Are you receiving both dialog prompts now? The "before" was a Network Level Authentication (NLA) prompt. Are you not seeing that at all now?

Comment: @GregAskew correct. I am not seeing the first dialog prompt now.

Comment: It sounds like NLA may be disabled on the server. There's a control panel app and a checkbox that can do that. Have a look at this article for the steps:  "Under the Remote Desktop group un-tick the checkbox Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (recommended)." but you want it ticked. https://kb.parallels.com/en/123661

Comment: I had a look at this. The option is disabled for me. It is unticked and disabled. I'm assuming this is a group policy that is disabling this. Is there an alternative setting that can be applied?